# Differentiability Of function Containig Min.f(t)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, continuity

> **Question** let f(x)= x$^{4}$-8x$^{3}+22x^{2}$-24x and g(x)=$\begin{cases}
> _{x-10}^{min.f(t)} & _{x\geq1}{}^{0\leq t\leq x,0\leq x\leq1}\end{cases}$ discuss the continuity and differentiability of g(x) in [-1,$\infty$)

I don't know what is meaning of max.f(t) and min.f(t). I wasted the whole

day in searching it on internet but i got nothing.I checked many
calculus books like Thomas calculus,Howard anton and many more. In
spivak i found two question on Min.(f,g),but that did'nt help.

**I am not here for the answer of this question** I want to solve
it myself.But i could not found any solid learing stuff throughout the
day

**Please Suggest me any reference book for the above question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x)=4 x^3-24 x^2+44 x-24=4 (x-3) (x-2) (x-1)$

$f'(x)<0$ on $[0,1]$ 
The function is decreasing, thus the minimum on $[0,x]$ is $f(x)$ for $0\le x\le 1$

Thus the function $g(x)$ is defined as

$
g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 x^4-8 x^3+22 x^2-24 x  & 0\leq t\leq x,0\leq x\leq 1\\
 x-10 & x\geq 1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

derivative is

$
g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 4 x^3-24 x^2+44 x-24  & 0\leq t\leq x,0\leq x\leq 1\\
 1 & x\geq 1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} g'(x)=0\ne \lim_{x\to 1^+} g'(x)=1$$
So $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=1$

Answer (score 4):

$\min.f(t), \ 0 \le t \le x $ is the minimum value of $f(x)$ in the interval $[0,x]$.

Comment: any book to study?

Comment: I have no idea... the standard stuff is good enough I think...

Comment: Where i can find the standard stuff